# Understanding of how CUITe framework works and can implement in a simple project?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, automation, coded-ui-tests

My manager asked me to give some inputs for the technical proposal on CUITe(Coded UI Test Enhanced Framework). I have downloaded the [CUITe 1.05 released](http://cuite.codeplex.com/downloads/get/340643). I found few articles/blogs says how it works:
[CUITe Framework (Coded UI Test)](http://automationspecialist.wordpress.com/2011/09/24/cuite-framework-coded-ui-test/), [CUITe Quick Start Guide](http://cuite.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Quick%20Start&referringTitle=Frequently%20Asked%20Questions). But still I am unaware about use of it, how it will help me in unit testing a simple "Helloworld" kind of project.

Can anybody please help me in understanding its use step wise with an example. Any idea, link will be appreciated. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Standard Coded UI testing will generate sometimes 200+ lines of code when you record just clicking a single button (especially in complex applications with several nested control containers, and custom controls).  Most of that generated code is rather redundant.  Since you didn't write it yourself, and there is a large amount of code, it becomes hard to read it and later fix something if you need to.

CUITe is meant to fix this stuff.  CUITe has several optimizations that reduce the amount of code generated, and it writes code in a way that is hopefully easy to maintain in the future.

Comment: Personally, I have started hand-coding most tests, but for starters CUITe makes life easier.  Also, I believe CUITe is only for web apps.

Comment: Can you please tell me for a standalone/desktop application if I developed a test project in coded UI Test then do I need the to install visual studio 2010 in the machine where I will run my application with coded UI test project ?

Comment: Kind of unrelated, but you want to use Test Controllers and Agents (so the bare minimum of VS is included on the test machine)
Check out these links:
[Set up Test Agents for Coded UI Tests](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee291332.aspx), and
[Configuring Test Controllers and Agents](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd648127.aspx)